# easy android unit test fail

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I have a simple activity with only one edittext which was set to "http://" in xml. Based on [google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html), I wrote some unit tests for status check. I want to practice unit test and pass all tests. But I cannot pass `testStateDestroy()` and `testStatePause()` (log shows `mUrlView=="changed"`). The code below is very easy, did I miss something? Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}




public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

private Activity mActivity;
private EditText mUrlView;

public MainActivityTest() {
    super("au.com.crystalfish.safeshare.activity", MainActivity.class);
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = this.getActivity();
    mUrlView = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(au.com.crystalfish.safeshare.R.id.url);
}

public void testPreconditions() {
    assertNotNull(mActivity);
    assertEquals(mUrlView.getText().toString(), "http://");
}

@UiThreadTest
public void testRotate() {
    mUrlView.setText("changed");
    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    assertEquals(mUrlView.getText().toString(), "changed");
}

@UiThreadTest
public void testStateDestroy() {
    mUrlView.setText("changed");
    assertEquals(mUrlView.getText().toString(), "changed");
    mActivity.finish();
    mActivity = this.getActivity();
    assertEquals(mUrlView.getText().toString(), "http://"); <===========should be "http://" since it is a new activity
}

@UiThreadTest
public void testStatePause() {
    Instrumentation mInstr = this.getInstrumentation();
    mInstr.callActivityOnPause(mActivity);
    mUrlView.setText("changed");
    mInstr.callActivityOnResume(mActivity);
    assertEquals(mUrlView.getText().toString(), "http://");<======should be "http://" since the text should bot be changed when the activity was paused
}
```

}

Comment: What are you intending to test ?

Comment: Hi dtmilano, I want to practice tdd and pass all tests.

Comment: I know that, but your Activity doesn't do anything special thus my question about what you are intending to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for your testStatePause() test I think that may be valid. Even if the activity is paused you are still free to modify it however you want since you still have a reference to it (or one of its textViews at least. In a test like this, you should change the value of the textView in the actual activity's onPause method, then use your testStatePause test to verify that onPause was called and did its job correctly, then do the same for onResume().

I'm not really familiar with Android's testing framework but maybe a similar issue is happening with your testStateDestroy() test. Your mUrlView could still be pointing to the old, finished Activity. The old activity is no longer valid but its widgets might be.